# Simulate sliding range selector with string values

Tags: javascript, html, html5

I need to have a range selector that accepts string values instead of integer value.
This is not possible with standard HTML, so I needed to simulate one by using (hidden) radio buttons that are coupled with the range selector and change the label of the range selector accordingly.

My code is a bit of a mess, though. Could you help me clean it up?

```js
{
  "use strict";
  console.clear()
  const selector = 'input[type="radio"][data-range-selector]'
  
  let radios = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el.name] = acc[el.name] || {form: el.form, elements: []}
    acc[el.name].elements.push({
      'element': el,
      'value': el.dataset.rangeValue,
      'selector': el.dataset.rangeSelector,
    })
    el.dataset.rangeValue = acc[el.name].elements.length - 1
    return acc
  }, {})
  
  
  const getRadio = el => {
    return el.form.querySelector(`input[type="radio"][data-range-value="${el.value}"]`)
  }
  
  const getLabelForInput = el => {
    return el.form.querySelector(`label[for="${el.id}"]`)
  }
  
  const getRangeSelector = el => {
    return el.form.querySelector(el.dataset.rangeSelector)
  }
  
  Object.keys(radios).forEach(key => {
    var rangeSelector = getRangeSelector(radios[key].elements[0].element)
    rangeSelector.setAttribute('max', radios[key].elements.length - 1);
    rangeSelector.dataset.key = key
    
    radios[key].form.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      if (e.target.matches('input[type="range"][data-key]')) {
        getLabelForInput(e.target).innerHTML = getLabelForInput(getRadio(e.target)).innerHTML
        getRadio(e.target).checked = true
        // getRangeSelector(e.target).value = e.target.dataset.rangeValue
      }
    })
  })

  // document.addEventListener('change', e => console.log(e.target.form))
}
```

```css
[data-range-selector], [data-range-selector] + label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Simulate a sliding range selector with string values</h1>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="evil" value="" id="evil" data-range-selector="#evil-range" /><label for="evil">Choose</label>
  <input type="radio" name="evil" value="one" id="evil-one" data-range-selector="#evil-range"  /><label for="evil-one">One</label>
  <input type="radio" name="evil" value="twin" id="evil-twin" / data-range-selector="#evil-range"  ><label for="evil-twin">Twin</label>
  <input type="radio" name="evil" value="six" id="evil-six" data-range-selector="#evil-range"  /><label for="evil-six">Six</label>
  <input type="radio" name="evil" value="666" id="evil-666" data-range-selector="#evil-range"  /><label for="evil-666">666</label>
  <input type="range" id="evil-range" min="0" value="0"><label for="evil-range">Choose</label>
</form>

<hr>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="good" value="" id="good" data-range-selector="#good-range" data-range-value="0" /><label for="good">Choose</label>
  <input type="radio" name="good" value="one" id="good-one" data-range-selector="#good-range" data-range-value="1" /><label for="good-one">One</label>
  <input type="radio" name="good" value="twin" id="good-twin" / data-range-selector="#good-range" data-range-value="2" ><label for="good-twin">Twin</label>
  <input type="radio" name="good" value="six" id="good-three" data-range-selector="#good-range" data-range-value="3" /><label for="good-three">Tree</label>

  <input type="range" id="good-range" min="0" value="0"><label for="good-range">Choose</label>
</form>
```